# Learning combinatorial optimization, online convex optimization, and submodular function maximization

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, convex-optimization

What is the best way to learn combinatorial optimization, online convex optimization, and submodular function maximization? I currently found textbooks online and papers related to these topics but I am looking for example problems to solve, specifically for submodular function maximization, with python/c++ code to solve the problem. Are there any recommendations and online resources which would enable to learn and apply these topics quickly? My mathematics background is up to graduate school-level linear algebra and probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A course on submodular function maximization to self-teach:

[EE596B - Submodular Functions, Optimization, and Applications to Machine Learning, Spring Quarter, 2014](https://people.ece.uw.edu/bilmes/classes/ee563/ee563_spring_2014/)
Has lectures and lecture notes to learn.